# zsh add command to new line

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use Zsh on windows 10

I need to write the command in new line.

[image]

Like bash

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is set up for your current theme in the file

```
${ZSH}/themes/${ZSH_THEME}.zsh-theme
```

and the variable `PROMPT='${user}${host}|'`. Insert a newline in this string and it will display when you reload the config. The quote characters are important.

```
PROMPT='${user}${host}
|'
```

Comment: ${ZSH}/themes/${ZSH_THEME}.zsh-theme
 this command not worked for me so i did mannually by
nano ~/.oh-my-zsh/thems/robbyrussell.zsh-theme

Comment: Will this work if just using zsh without oh-my-zsh and the themes it provides?

Comment: @lacostenycoder yes it will, PS1/PROMPT is global to the system and not ohmyzsh specific :)